# npm ERR! npm owner error triggered with H10 app crashed

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am trying to execute the application but i am facing NPM errors in the log.What might be the reason.

> 2017-02-14T17:57:20.698084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't
>   available, you can get their info via:
>   2017-02-14T17:57:20.697188+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. 2017-02-14T17:57:20.697375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the
>   author that this fails on your system:
>   2017-02-14T17:57:20.697706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   2017-02-14T17:57:20.698436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above. 2017-02-14T17:57:20.698248+00:00
>   app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm owner ls Sap-api-ai
>   2017-02-14T17:57:20.717695+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include
>   the following file with any support request:
>   2017-02-14T17:57:20.831148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2017-02-14T17:57:20.777084+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 1 2017-02-14T17:58:48.330160+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=sap-api-ai-google.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=db57d06b-4cd6-41f8-aaf6-6688e0603f97 fwd="49.206.119.184"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-02-14T17:58:49.862288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=sap-api-ai-google.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=665fc337-8aec-46ec-914a-3e6b0990a2b5 fwd="49.206.119.184"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your code, but if I had to guess you're binding a static port rather than letting Heroku set your port for you via the PORT environment variable.

If you have something like:

```
app.listen(3000, (e) => { console.log('Connected!'); });
```

Then you'll want to change out that port number for the variable:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (e) => { console.log('Connected!'); });
```