# Node.js app not opening after deploy to Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, deployment, production-environment

I've gone through a number of revisions in my code, and have read various conflicting blog posts on similar issues. **App opens locally correctly.**

Additional steps I've taken:

- Cleared and re-added nodejs buildpackm Scaled the app according to Heroku docs 
  (heroku ps:scale web=0)
  (heroku ps:scale web=1), restarted the heroku app. Finally, I've used the following answers to similar questions:

[Error while deploying Node.js App to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480472/error-while-deploying-node-js-app-to-heroku)

[Heroku is giving me a 503 when trying to open my web app, works on local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596835/heroku-is-giving-me-a-503-when-trying-to-open-my-web-app-works-on-local-host)

[npm ERR! npm owner error triggered with H10 app crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233437/npm-err-npm-owner-error-triggered-with-h10-app-crashed)

In my opinion, the significant error from logs is: "heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed".

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Heroku logs:

```
macs-iMac:hooptime mac$ heroku logs
2017-07-27T03:13:32.290426+00:00 app[web.1]: Available on:
2017-07-27T03:13:32.291372+00:00 app[web.1]:   http://localhost:8000
2017-07-27T03:13:32.291437+00:00 app[web.1]: Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
2017-07-27T03:14:24.468772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-27T03:14:24.329875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-07-27T03:14:24.329968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-07-27T03:14:24.452131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-07-27T03:17:53.555938+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-27T03:17:58.615372+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2017-07-27T03:17:59.234914+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-27T03:18:01.127773+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028085+00:00 app[worker.1]: module.js:471
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028104+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028105+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028105+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028112+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028121+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028122+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028123+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028123+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028124+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-07-27T03:18:01.028125+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-07-27T03:18:01.111007+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-27T03:32:56.591479+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-27T03:33:00.576960+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2017-07-27T03:33:01.200876+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638384+00:00 app[worker.1]: module.js:471
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638400+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638401+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638402+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638402+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638415+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638415+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638416+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638417+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638417+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-07-27T03:33:02.638418+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-07-27T03:33:02.769228+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-27T03:33:02.782955+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-07-27T03:36:58.088482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=04c12935-8d88-470d-9e54-4b45e2480d67 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:00.556550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=270fea8f-75fe-4078-8c01-c8779e5c43cb fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:12.960183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=d31437be-fe7e-4e56-a0db-a13a8e3a28af fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:13.804392+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-27T03:48:14.158976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=d9cdb0e6-ab58-442f-b35b-87e72ae2cc18 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:14.505616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=de46bfff-578e-4e5e-be86-c51b58b4af54 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:14.661681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=e51259a7-0979-412d-8f93-b571e28875ef fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:14.743144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/apple-touch-icon.png" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=fb7cd369-d821-44a1-bf30-5e378f1810fb fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:15.011171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=82649af8-1b1c-4215-827b-41af4d827500 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:15.276467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=fe831747-d46d-4ae2-9475-64bed439abb3 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:15.599565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/apple-touch-icon.png" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=7e6fd0fa-efc7-40b6-b2da-125673765285 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:17.042432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=4b51a77b-ae59-4583-b386-526f0a501c68 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:17.149974+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2017-07-27T03:48:17.380527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=73136e3a-46b7-4c92-9f2a-d581d3c72738 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:48:17.829826+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457599+00:00 app[worker.1]: module.js:471
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457612+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457612+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457613+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457614+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457615+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457614+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457616+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457616+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457618+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-07-27T03:48:19.457617+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-07-27T03:48:19.568292+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-27T03:48:19.582653+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-07-27T03:53:32.129097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=70af7304-5591-4cff-9fc7-25c309e6df5b fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:53:32.359600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=13b24996-5231-46ce-bf16-0917f438d67c fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:54:22.676504+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=1b37ef83-7165-4f51-8028-e6e7c9223c30 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:54:22.902471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=bab64ebe-b273-4b57-94e9-c795833e0f68 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:56:00.492646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=4bb60171-35b7-4fe0-afd9-f4c43d4357b9 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:56:00.721576+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=2dee01f7-5392-40b5-b9d2-38178f32e698 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:56:02.052904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=15afa6fc-8216-48f9-a637-92c82506b4ce fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:56:02.265575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=998e5185-b367-4121-9bdc-5673d37deeff fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:57:27.796870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=e753734d-79ed-4c36-8e6f-08e591edafee fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:57:28.036446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=e0147f98-9f83-4c51-a6c8-cb3d9c46c47b fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:58:30.003002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=00c1688f-740f-4cbf-9d0d-cc6c25d23cf4 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:58:30.226148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=c7c59508-0d33-4e98-b2a3-4c8ebfd8529f fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:58:30.878029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=ec7d5038-82eb-4c12-aed6-0488401f7a9e fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T03:58:31.085787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=15f39eec-de96-48f0-8f6b-575cd688ba91 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T04:02:16.853379+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-27T04:02:21.100226+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2017-07-27T04:02:21.727262+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099454+00:00 app[worker.1]: module.js:471
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099481+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099482+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099482+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099484+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099483+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099485+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099485+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099486+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099486+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-07-27T04:02:23.099487+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
2017-07-27T04:02:23.189149+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-27T04:02:23.199937+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-07-27T04:03:40.500129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=e1058a8e-46a1-4372-a702-f616540f792a fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T04:03:40.730673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=3ffc8109-d893-43fc-8478-132ef1744a3d fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T04:03:41.990804+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=fd31d62c-c0f9-4acc-b72c-3d80d1d0d362 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-07-27T04:03:42.209388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hooptime.herokuapp.com request_id=5b07975b-ffe1-43e6-8d72-7acf905d4bf2 fwd="66.205.150.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
macs-iMac:hooptime mac$
```

Procfile:

```
worker: node index.js
```

package.json:

```
        {
  "name": "hooptime",
  "description": "Our sample Node to Heroku app",
  "engines": { "node": "7.1.0"},
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.8"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
     var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/parks/');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('register.view.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
});
```

[image: structure of app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Procfile you defined worker as

```
worker: node index.js
```

But your main file is named server.js so you should define Procfile as

```
worker: node server.js
```

Comment: Hi @arpit
Thank you for your response. I went ahead and made that change, however am still getting another error mentioned in my logs which states: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'

I am running the application from the root project path and I can confirm that there is an index.js file. I've updated my question with the code that resides in index.js. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If your Procfile and server.js are not in same directory then you have to put relative path in worker and I would suggest renaming the file as index.js

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestions. I took your advice and:
1. renamed server. js --> index.js
2. updated/moved both Procfile and the newly renamed index.js to the root of the project directory
3. condensed my package.json
I have added my new logs and files to the question, and added a screenshot of the structure of my project. I am continuing to see the error of "Cant find module:/app/index.js" whether I move index.js in or out of the app directory. I have restarted the app via heroku, re-scaled the worker, and re-pushed the code to heroku. Any other solution that comes to mind?

Comment: It should be `app/index.js` and I think you did put `/app/index.js` which might be wrong